# Contents of cell in tableview not displayed as expected

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a **UITableView** (Dynamic) which is used as a **Settings** menu.
These cells can be tapped and an "inline" cell will open with for instance a date picker or a valuePicker. (Cell expand-collapse)

This works all fine as expected.

Now I added a new **Menu** option that also opens an inline cell beneath it, with 4 **UITextField**.

The strange thing is now that the inline cell is displayed opened but the content for that cell (the 4 **UITextField**) are shown a bit earlier.
So, the cell is being expanded, but the content is already shown.

When collapsing the cell the same thing happens. The cell is collapsed but contents is just a bit lazy and just a little late

Comment: Could you provide screenshots? I'm finding it a bit hard to visualise your problem.

Comment: Provide your didSelectItemAt or relevant code to tableview

Comment: you can check for cell's height in tableview's heightForRow method and based on expanded/collapsed height, you can hide/unhide the textfields

Comment: Seems to constraints related issue. Can you add code which shows how the expand/collapse animation is done.

Comment: Thanks guys... I will look into that constraint issue..

Comment: @Zack: A screenshot is hard because the issue hard to see, but it is there, I you notice it, you see it all the time